# Multiple ListViews Create programmatically in android

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I have tried to create n number of listviews programmatically in android. But the Adapter UI Always showing the last listview elements in all the listviews.

for example: i want to create 20 listview programmatically and every listview have different row values. But in all the 20 listviews shows the same listview element, which are the elements of my 20th listview.

Please check the below code:

```
  LinearLayout linear = findViewById(R.id.linear);
    ListView modeList;
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
        modeList = new ListView(this);
        stringArrayList.clear();
        for(int k=0; k<=2; k++){
            stringArrayList.add("i="+i);
        }
        ListAdapters childChooseMusicAdapter = new ListAdapters(this, stringArrayList);
        modeList.setAdapter(childChooseMusicAdapter);
        linear.addView(modeList);
    }
```

when the above code run it shows all the 20 listviews, but the data of all the listview are same.

and in the output shows:

```
**list 0**
i= 20
i= 20
i= 20

**list 1**
i= 20
i= 20
i= 20

-
-
-

**list 20**
i= 20
i= 20
i= 20
```

But I want the output like this:

```
**list 0**
i= 0
i= 0
i= 0

**list 1**
i= 1
i= 1
i= 1

-
-
-

**list 20**
i= 20
i= 20
i= 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the **stringArrayList** object is same for all the adapters, it shows the last updated item in all listviews. so create new arraylist for each listview as follows,

```
LinearLayout linear = findViewById(R.id.linear);
ListView modeList;
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;
for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
   modeList = new ListView(this);
   stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int k=0; k<=2; k++){
      stringArrayList.add("i="+i);
   }
   ListAdapters childChooseMusicAdapter = new ListAdapters(this, stringArrayList);
   modeList.setAdapter(childChooseMusicAdapter);
   linear.addView(modeList);
 }
```